# Python not finding array in locals() even though it is there

Tags: python, arrays

I am making an algorithm that converts numbers into roman numerals, which involves an array. However, when I run my code, I tell it to check if they array exists, and create it if it doesn't (I use this complex method because the code has to restart itself a lot, you will see).

```
number = input("What number would you like to convert?")
number = int(number)
def alg(n):
if 'roman' in locals():
    print("yes")
    if n >= 1000:
        roman = roman + ["M"]
        n = n - 1000
        print(roman)
        print(n)
        #alg(number)
    else:
        print("end")
else:
    print("no")
    roman = [""]
    print(len(roman))
    print(locals())
    alg(number)
alg(number)
```

I have tried researching it on the Python documentation and on this site, but to no avail.

Comment: "even though it's there" - no, it's not there.

Comment: @jonrsharpe: I always wonder why people change the text, but not the indent of the code when they edit questions ...

Comment: @elegent because indentation matters in Python, and only the OP can tell us what it actually is.

Comment: @jonrsharpe: Fair enough :) That was my point. But in this case it's clear IMO ;)

Answer (score 2):

Every invocation of a function has its own set of local variables. Your check will always return `false`, because you have just entered the function.

If you want to keep the recursive implementation that you currently have, you should pass the `roman` variable as a second parameter to the `alg` function.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you want to find it in `locals()` (which will only look in the scope of your function `alg` which is just starting, thus cannot containing your `roman` variable) ?
Maybe you want to look up into *globals variables* with `globals()` ?

Comment: It's not in globals, either.  It exists in locals *after* it's created.  The only user-level globals are **alg** and **number**.

Comment: Well I see that the `roman` variable is created later in `alg` (so yes it exists in locals after that) but I said that thinking that the OP may have not shown his entire code and may have defined a `roman` variable upstream (in the global scope, at the same level of `number`) and just wasn't searching it in the appropriate place.

Comment: No that is the whole program. I think I've figures out what's wrong and I'll let you know later.

Answer (score 0):

You check for the word 'roman' in **locals**; this is not going to happen, as you have yet to define **roman**.  A function's locals do not persist from call to call.

Your decrement

```
n = n - 1000
```

doesn't do anything useful (yet).  The local copy of **n** gets changed, but you never use it.  The original copy (from the main program) is still intact, as integers are not mutable.

Note that your recursive call passes **number** -- the main program's original number.  You're always converting the original, never working on the smaller quantity.

I'll stop here: without design, structure, or comments, this code is a bit hard to follow.